# How to do File creation and manipulation in functional style?

Tags: scala

I need to write a program where I run a set of instructions and create a file in a directory. Once the file is created, when the same code block is run again, it should not run the same set of instructions since it has already been executed before, here the file is used as a guard.

```
var Directory: String = "Dir1"
var dir: File = new File("Directory");
dir.mkdir();

var FileName: String = Directory + File.separator + "samplefile" + ".log"
val FileObj: File = new File(FileName)

if(!FileObj.exists())
    // blahblah
else 
{
    // set of instructions to create the file
}
```

When the programs runs initially, the file won't be present, so it should run the set of instructions in `else` and also create the file, and after the first run, the second run it should exit since the file exists.

The problem is that I do not understand `new File`, and when the file is created? Should I use `file.CreateNewFile`? Also, how to write this in functional style using `case`?

Comment: Three small points, unrelated to the question. It's a good idea to respect the Scala naming conventions: use `var directory` instead of `var Directory`, etc (see the [Scala style guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/)). You should avoid using `var` where you can use `val`: use `val Directory` instead of `var Directory`. Finally, it's better to avoid concatenating pathnames as strings, and use the other constructors of the class `File` instead, like this: `val directory = new File("Dir1"); val file = new File(directory, "samplefile.log")` - that way, you don't need to worry about separators.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's important to understand that a [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) is not a physical file on the file system, but a representation of a pathname -- per the javadoc: *"An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames"*. So `new File(...)` has nothing to do with creating an actual file - you are just defining a pathname, which may or may not correspond to an existing file.

To create an empty file, you can use:

```
val file = new File("filepath/filename")
file.createNewFile();
```

If running on JRE 7 or higher, you can use the new [java.nio.file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) API:

```
val path = Paths.get("filepath/filename")
Files.createFile(path)
```

If you're not happy with the default IO APIs, you an consider a number of alternative. Scala-specific ones that I know of are:

- [scala-io](https://github.com/jesseeichar/scala-io)
- [rapture.io](http://rapture.io/)

Or you can use libraries from the Java world, such as [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) or [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/).

Edit: One thing I did not consider initially: I understood "creating a file" as "creating an empty file"; but if you intend to write something *immediately* in the file, you generally don't need to create an empty file first.