# Scala - delete file if exist, the Scala way

Tags: scala, delete-file

How to nicely delete file in Scala, "the Scala way"?

For example, i can use something like this, very *Java* style:

```
  private def deleteFile(path: String) = {
    val fileTemp = new File(path)
    if (fileTemp.exists) {
       fileTemp.delete()
    }
  }
```

How would it be implemented in Scala, in a more functional syntax?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can't get rid of side effects while doing `IO`-operations, so no good functional ways here. All functional stuff is actually ends when you start to interact with user/devices directly, no monad can help you to do one external side-effect; however, you can describe (wrap) sequential side-effects using [IO](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/IO+Monad.html)-like Monads.

Talking about your example, monad-restyled code may look like:

```
implicit class FileMonads(f: File) {
  def check = if (f.exists) Some(f) else None //returns "Maybe" monad
  def remove = if (f.delete()) Some(f) else None //returns "Maybe" monad
}

for {
  foundFile <- new File(path).check
  deletedFile <- foundFile.remove
} yield deletedFile

res11: Option[java.io.File] = None
```

But that's too verbose without any real advantages if you **just** want to  delete one file. More than that, `fileTemp.exists` check has no sense and actually isn't reliable (as @Eduardo pointed out). So, even in Scala the best way I know is [FileUtils.deleteQuietly](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteQuietly(java.io.File)):

```
  FileUtils.deleteQuietly(new File(path))
```

Or even

```
  new File(path).delete()
```

It won't throw an exception for non-existent file - just return `false`.

If you really want something more Scala-way - look at [rapture.io](http://rapture.io/) for example:

```
  val file = uri"file:///home/work/garbage"
  file.delete()
```

Or [scala-io](https://github.com/jesseeichar/scala-io). 
More info: [How to do File creation and manipulation in functional style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206903/how-to-do-file-creation-and-manipulation-in-functional-style)

P.S. However IO-monads might be useful (unlike Some/None in my case) when you require asynchronous operations, so naive code (without cats/scalaz) would look like:

```
implicit class FileMonads(f: File) {
  def check = Future{ f.exists } //returns "Future" monad
  def remove = Future{ f.remove } //returns "Future" monad
}

for {
  exists <- new File(path).check
  _ <- if (exists) foundFile.remove else Future.unit
}
```

Of course, in the real world, it's best to use some NIO-wrappers like [FS2-io](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2): https://lunatech.com/blog/WCl5OikAAIrvQCoc/functional-io-with-fs2-streams

Comment: Just nitpicking, but, int the first alternative, there is a small possibility that the file gets deleted by another process between verifying that it exists and the deletion statement.

Comment: @Eduardo and you've got `None` then, which is correct :)

Comment: @Eduardo just fo fun, I've promised `Monad`-style here (flatMap), not just `Functor` (map). Seriously, the simillar check in OP's question also has no sense - I've just translated it to monadic.

Comment: Also, on jdk7+ you can use `Files.deleteIfExists(file.toPath)` or `Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("path/to/file"))`

Comment: @KonstantinGribov just to note that it ain't atomic as well

Answer (score 0):

[os-lib](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib) allows you to elegantly delete a file if it exists:

```scala
val file = os.pwd/"cats"/"cat1.txt"
if (os.exists(file)) os.remove(file)
```

os-lib is way cleaner that using Java libraries directly.  See [here](https://mungingdata.com/scala/filesystem-paths-move-copy-list-delete-folders/) for more details on the lib.